# Sonarqube does not show Tests from different gradle source sets

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, jacoco, sonarqube-scan

We are trying to setup sonarqube analysis for our multi module gradle project.
One of the subprojects has an additional source set for integration tests.
As mentioned in documentation and other Stackoverflow-Threads we are currently using this configuration in the build.gradle from the subproject:

```
    sonarqube() {
    properties {
        property "sonar.jacoco.reportPaths", ["$buildDir/jacoco/test.exec", "$buildDir/jacoco/integrationTest.exec"]
        // TODO: Why is not this working?, see doc at https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle
        // which says this is the way to go
        properties["sonar.tests"] += sourceSets.integrationTest.allSource.srcDirs.findAll({ it.exists() })
    }
}
```

The first property works correct. Sonarqube shows a higher Code-Coverage caused by the integration tests. 
But the integration test itself is not shown as a Test in Sonarqube. 
Because it runs in a specific task, we also tried to extend the sonar task

```
project.tasks["sonarqube"].dependsOn integrationTest
```

Then the integration tests are executed before sonar analysis, but does not change the result, the test is still not shown in Sonarqube UI.

What is sonarqubes source for showing up test classes? We thought it would be the source sets, but that did not seem to be the case?

Comment: I've only seen a different pattern in use:

`sonarqube {` // without brackets
and
`property "sonar.tests", "src/test, src/integrationTest"` // not `properties`, comma-separated list